# How to get the source element on a button click event handler? iView

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, iview

In iView, all UI elements are rendered by return data of "render" function, for example , i have the following data:

```
h('Button', {
props: {
    type: 'warning',
    size: 'small',
    disabled: params.row.disabled
},
style: {
    marginTop: '5px',
    marginRight: '5px',
    marginBottom: '5px'
},
on: {
    click: () => {
        this.checkDataOne(params.row);
    }
}
}, 'check data')
```

which will show a button. I want to disable this button on the beginning of click event, and enable it in the end(there's an asynchronous operation in checkDataOne function). But how can i get the button?

I tried "window.event.srcElement", but it return a span element, which is enclosed in the button.

Comment: what if you added parameter to the function passed to click? click: ($event) => { ... }? then $event.target should be what you're looking for...

Comment: $event.target reference the span also

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `window.event.srcElement` to get the `span` element inside the button, you can look for the closest `button` element surrounding it.

So your code to get the source element would become:

```
window.event.srcElement.closest("button");
```

You can change the `"button"` to any specific selector you need in order to target the button.

Comment: Yes, i can. But it will depend on dom structure rendered by iView, and the structure is not documented, so not stable. I'd like to find an "official" method to get the button.